# React hook useRef() variable is null on Android, but works on iOS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

So I have a  component, which is wrapped by a  component, the  component has a ref:

```js
const viewRef = useRef(null);
...
<View ref={ viewRef }>
```

The  component also has a function that triggers upon being pressed

```js
// locationX is the location of tapping relative to <View>
const tapSliderGesture = (locationX) => {
  // we need the ViewRef to measure its size (width) and position relative to screen (px)
  viewRef.current.measure((fx, fy, width, height, px) => {
    const location = Math.round(((locationX - px) / width) * steps);
    if (location !== state) {
      setState(location);
    }
  });
};
...
<View ref={ viewRef } onResponderMove={ (evt) => { tapSliderGesture(evt.nativeEvent.locationX); } }>
```

However, on android `ViewRef.current` is always null inside `tapSliderGesture`, funnily enough, `ViewRef.current` is *not* null within the component and outside the `tapSliderGesture`.

Full example below:

```js
const AddSlider = ({setState, state, steps}) => {
  const viewRef = useRef(null);
  console.log('On render', viewRef.current); // prints after every re-render
  // viewRef.current is not null after a render is triggered in the component
  const tapSliderGesture = (locationX) => {
    console.log(viewRef.current); // on iOS this prints the ref object
                                  // on Android it prints null
    viewRef.current.measure((fx, fy, width, height, px) => {
      const location = Math.round(((locationX - px) / width) * steps);
      if (location !== state) {
        setState(location);
      }
    });
  };
  return (
      <View
        ref={ viewRef }
        onResponderMove={ (evt) => { tapSliderGesture(evt.nativeEvent.locationX); } }
        onResponderGrant={ (evt) => { tapSliderGesture(evt.nativeEvent.locationX); } }
      >
        <Slider .../>
      </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

So the issue is that android has some sort of optimization which changes the DOM hierarchy tree. The answer was to add `collapsable: false` prop to my view, so:

```
<View ref={ viewRef } collapsable={ false } .../>
```

That fixed it...

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3282

Another workaround mentioned is adding an empty `onLayout` prop to the view node: `onLayout={() => {}}`